# Getting answer as remainder instead of quotient

Tags: java

When I run it I get this:

```
Enter 2 Integers, Do note that you will Get a Quotient and a Remainder.
Enter the First Number: 3
Now enter the Second Number: 9
Your Quotient is: 0
Your Remainder is: 3
```

It should be:

```
Enter 2 Integers, Do note that you will Get a Quotient and a Remainder.
Enter the First Number: 3
Now enter the Second Number: 9
Your Quotient is: 3
Your Remainder is: 0
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Remainder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0, b = 0, quotient, remainder;
        int smallerNumber = 0;
        int biggerNumber = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter 2 Integers, Do note that you will Get a Quotient and a Remainder.");
        System.out.print("Enter the First Number: ");
        a = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Now enter the Second Number: ");
        b = reader.nextInt();

        remainder = (a % b);

        quotient = (a / b);
        remainder = (a % b);

        if(a > b){
            biggerNumber = a;
            a = b;
        }else{
            smallerNumber = a;
            biggerNumber = b;
        }
        System.out.print("Your Quotient is: ");
        System.out.println(quotient);
        if (remainder > 0){
            System.out.print("Your Remainder is: ");
            System.out.println(remainder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It always helps to run things through a debugger or set up a simple test of `System.out.println(9 % 3);` to see what you get and that you are doing it right.

Answer (score 3):

You are entering the numbers in the wrong order. You are doing `a / b`, and `3 / 9` in integer math is zero. Enter 9 first, and 3 second, and things will work.

Note also that you are looking for the bigger and smaller number after computing the remainder and quotient (and you compute the former twice). Swap the order of the code, and divide `bigger/smaller` for better results...

```
  System.out.println("Enter 2 Integers, Do note that you will Get a Quotient and a Remainder.");
  System.out.print("Enter the First Number: ");
  a = reader.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Now enter the Second Number: ");
  b = reader.nextInt();

  if(a > b){
      biggerNumber = a;
      smallerNumber = b;
  } 
  else {
      smallerNumber = a;
      biggerNumber = b;
  }
  remainder = biggerNumber % smallerNumber;
  quotient = biggerNumber / smallerNumber;
```

Comment: My program is supposed to not assume that the integers are entered in any order. So if the user enters 3 as the first number and 9 as the second number it should rearrange it to make it valid.

Comment: Which is why you need to do your sorting (bigger / smaller) **before** you compute the result - and then actually **use** the result of your sorting... My updated code should make that pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have a and b backwards. Instead,

```
quotient = b / a;
remainder = b % a;
```

Also, a and b should probably be renamed to first and second...